# How to change default texts in datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatable

I create a data table in my HTML template. It works totally good but I have an issue.
I did not create my project in English. So, I have to change some text in the table.
Like "search" should be "ara" etc...
How can I do that?

```
<table id="example" class="display table  table-hover grid_" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Kullanıcı</th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <body>
    ...
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable( {
                select: true
            } );
        } );
</script>
```

Note: I marked the texts that I want to change.
[image: datatable]

Answer (score 1):

To change the default texts of datatable, you'll need to fix it while initializing the datatable. There are two methods by which you can include internationalization options in DataTables - loading the language file through an Ajax request (language.url), or at initialization time using the language property. The following example shows how to include the Turkish translation as an Ajax file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        language: {
            url: 'dataTables.turkish.json'
        }
    });
});
```

Or, you can change the default texts by using the `language` option while initializing the datatable. Here is the example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        language: {
            "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
            "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries",
            "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
            "infoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
            "search": "Search:",
            "paginate": {
                "first": "First",
                "last": "Last",
                "next": "Next",
                "previous": "Previous"
            },
        }
    });
});
```

You can also check this links:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/i18n()
https://datatables.net/reference/option/language

Comment: @amelvin, Last time instead of commenting to the post, I answered to the question with the comment content. Now I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Sayfa başına _MENU_ kayıt göster",
                "zeroRecords": "Kayıt Bulunamadı",
                "info": " _PAGE_ / _PAGES_",
                "search": "Ara",
            }
        } );
    } );
</script>
```